# ES6 import from multiple paths

Tags: javascript, import, ecmascript-6, module

Let's say I have some classes that extend an object.  One class is nested deeper than the other.

```
-- FOOD.js
export default class FOOD {}...

-- FRUIT.js
import FOOD from './FOOD.js';
export default class FRUIT extends FOOD {}...

-- FRUIT/APPLE.js
import FRUIT from '../FRUIT.js';
export default class APPLE extends FRUIT {}...

-- FRUIT/SEEDLESS/ORANGE
import FRUIT from '../../FRUIT.js';
export default class ORANGE extends FRUIT {}...

-- main.js
import FRUIT from './FRUIT.js';
import APPLE from './FRUIT/APPLE.js';
import ORANGE from './FRUIT/SEEDLESS/ORANGE.js';

let orange = new ORANGE();
let apple = new APPLE();
```

I get an uncaught ReferenceError from APPLE.js saying "FRUIT is not defined"

I assume that the relative path to FRUIT gets overwritten.  Can I have multiple paths to the 'FRUIT' alias?  Do I have to create individual aliases for the import?

Comment: Where does the error originate? On what line? Imports are scoped (using Babel) and variables shouldn’t overwrite each other.

Comment: The ReferenceError originates from APPLE.js.  Inspector doesn't seem to give me anything else to go by.

Comment: I’ll try and duplicate when I can. For now I reckon it might be to do with the file and the folder having the same name, but I cannot confirm that.

Comment: I'm realizing now that the example I provided might not be giving enough detail.  Technically, FRUIT also extends something like FOOD.  In this case, FOOD was missing an import statement for one of its own dependencies.  May have solved my own problem

Comment: Yeah. It’s a good idea to always include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the lowest level ReferenceError is what gets shown in the inspector.  For those with nested imports, be sure to check your imports on each dependent module.